# The Chinese of "Browse Teachers" : 访问老师？

Tags: translation

I have a tutoring website with many teachers on it. On the front page, there is a button to browse the profiles of all the teachers.

- Is `访问老师` the correct translation?

Comment: No. But the literal translation "浏览老师" sounds a little stiff and strange to me either. Maybe just "Teachers' Profiles", 教师简况 or something like that would be more natural to Chinese speakers.

Answer (score 8):

I think "师资介绍" is better. As a Chinese native speaker, It's very intertesting for me to got this site. :D hahaha

Comment: 我想了好久该怎么说才不别扭，只能说你太有才了

Answer (score 2):

I suggest..  师资简介 . hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Browse - as in to browse online is:

浏览

Key dictionary says:
1 browse (on the web)
2 glance over

But if you want to say browse as in "I'm just browsing" (when the shopkeeper asks you what you're looking for) would just be a simple 看看.

Hope that helps.

edit: a better translation might just be "详细资料"....

Answer (score 1):

I agree with kayneo. “师资介绍” is the saying that we would pick up.

Comment: It's not an answer. If you agree with other answer you can just upvote on it.